# Transfer to JSON file

Tags: python

I am a newb to python and I am about to transfer a large amount of data into a certain format in Python. The data looks like this

`0(0127),0(0128),0(0129)`(All in String)
and I want this change to

```
'0127': '0',
'0128': '0' ,
.....
```

I am wondering if there is a good way to do this.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = '0(0127),0(0128),0(0129)'
dictionery = {}
for x in string.split(','):
    splitDictionery = x.replace('(', ' ').replace(')','').split(' ')
    dictionery[splitDictionery[1]] = splitDictionery[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I also tried the remove method and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using explicit looping (with a for loop etc), we can use an ugly but straightforward one-liner list comprehension.

```
from json import dumps

# just using your example data 
s = "0(0127),0(0128),0(0129)"

# output is in correct JSON forma
output = dumps([{x.split('(')[1][:-1] : x.split('(')[0]} for x in s.split(',')])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try it!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this will perform on your large data. But, you can give it a try.

```
# load your data/string
inputString = "0(0127),0(0128),0(0129)"

# split by comma
splitCommaString = inputString.split(",")

# create a dictionary which you can dump as a json later
mydict = {}

# iterate on your comma separated list
for mystr in splitCommaString:
    val, key = mystr.split("(")
    key = key.rstrip(")")
    mydict[key] = val
# or you can dump it to a json using json module
print(mydict)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response,  I think it is really helpful.